# OpenGL. Мигают стыки

Tags: python, opengl, graphics

Пытаюсь разобраться с OpenGL
Рисую несколько кубов. При вращении получившегося параллелепипеда мигают стыки граней соседних кубов: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который рисует куб:

```
def CubeQ(offset, cube):
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    k = 0
    for quadrate in quadrates:
        glColor3fv(cube.get_color(k))
        for vertex in quadrate:
            vert = list(verticies[vertex])
            for i in range(len(vert)):
                vert[i] += offset[i]
            glVertex3fv(tuple(vert))
        k += 1
    glEnd()
```

offset - кортеж, который задает "сдвиг" куба от начала координат. 
Как это можно исправить? (Что <strike>погуглить</strike> почитать и т.д.?)

Comment: "сдвиг" куба от начала координат" это лучше делать трансформациями.

Comment: Что находится в verticies?

Comment: @Unick в verticies находятся координаты вершин куба со стороной длины 1

Answer (score 1):

- Увеличьте глубину Z буффера до 24 бит, например.
- Уменьшите расстояние между плоскостями отсечения Z_NEAR и Z_FAR.
- Сделайте тест глубины GL_LEQUAL.
- Не рисуйте невидимые грани кубов.
- Замените кубы на цельную геометрию.